# Underscores not displayed in WPF

Tags: wpf, accessor

On my whole application, I've some underscores (_) which are not displayed.

It's due to the accessor. But how can I disable it? Application wide? I don't have them on labels, textboxes, ...

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable WPF label accelerator key (text underscore is missing)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40733/disable-wpf-label-accelerator-key-text-underscore-is-missing)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To disable underscores globally for all labels you can override the default template for labels like this:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type Label}"
       TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                      RecognizesAccessKey="False"
                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                             Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

It differs from the default template in this line: `RecognizesAccessKey="False"`.

Put this style in global resources of your application (`App.xaml`) and your labels will not recognize underscores anymore.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your response! I will try that today, but seems to be what I need. Is it mandatory to bind default values?

Comment: @J4N - You don't need to bind anything. Just put this style in global resources (in App.xaml) and it will be automatically applied to all Labels in your application (unless other style is explicitly specified on a label).

Comment: Excuse me, I was speaking about these kind of things:
Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
Are they mandatory? Because if I've to do that for all components which are supposed to display something, I would like to reduce the amount of code for it

Comment: @J4N - Yes, it is mandatory as long as you want to preserve the all the functionality of the control. For example, if you remove Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" then setting Padding on Labels in your application will not work.

Comment: Okay, Can I find somewhere default template? Because I've to customize this for several components

Comment: @J4N - The default templates are included with Expression Blend installation. You can find them in the following folder: "<Expression Blend installation path>\SystemThemes\Wpf".

Comment: I'm using visual studio to design them, is there any chance to use resources in visual studio?

Comment: @J4N - Of course you can use the resources in Visual Studio. Just in order to get the default control resource you need to install Expression Blend. Once you got the resources, you can copy them in your project and then you can remove Blend.

Comment: This solution is in my opinion the best solution, since adding a second underscore is just a workaround with possible side effects.

Answer (score 10):

Use two underscores:

```
name = "__something";
```

Comment: I can't use this, theses values comes from the database, and I just can't afford me to do this on every field. And most of my fields are directly bounds on the value of my objects.

Comment: Use a value converter to replace underscore with double underscore. Easy.

Answer (score 9):

One easy solution is to not use <Label>. <TextBox> doesn't mess with underscores.

Comment: or TextBlock if you don't want to deal with something being editable. Bind to `Text` instead of `Content`.

Comment: If using TextBox instead of a Label I'd also set IsReadOnly to True and IsTabStop to False

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried doubling the underscores?

Comment: why it is happening that double underscore is showing not single ?

Comment: @Ahmad because the underscore indicates that the next letter is the access key (used with Alt; eg. the Text "_Ahmad" would allow to access it via Alt + A as indicated by underline). So two underscores are the escape sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem for `Button` & `Label` Control where the underscore inside the content was not displayed. I also want the fix without changing the look and feel of the Button or Label. I got the idea from this question on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734825/custom-button-template-in-wpf). I tried using `doubling the underscores`, but it had its issues when you tried to access the content of the label or button you now have to convert double underscore to single.

I implemented the solution using DataTemplate applied through style to ContentControl. I set `RecognizesAccessKey="False"` for the ContentPresenter.As both `Label` & `Button` control derive from `ContentControl` with Content Property. So We have to apply the style to them using the `BasedOn` attribute as shown in the code.

Here is how the UI looks before and after the fix:
[image]

Here is the code for MainWindow.xaml to test:

```
<Window x:Class="ContentControlWithUnderscore.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="Height" Width="300">

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Background="LightBlue" >Original Text:</TextBlock>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Some_Text"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="Some__Text"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="Som_e_Text"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>

        <TextBlock Background="LightBlue">Original Problem:</TextBlock>

        <StackPanel >
            <Button Content="Some_Text"></Button>
            <Button Content="Some__Text"></Button>
            <Button Content="Som_e_Text"></Button>
            <Label Content="Some_Text"></Label>
            <Label Content="Some__Text"></Label>
            <Label Content="Som_e_Text"></Label>
        </StackPanel>

        <TextBlock Background="LightBlue">After Fix:</TextBlock>

        <StackPanel >
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                               <ContentPresenter RecognizesAccessKey="False" Content="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContentControl}}}"></ContentPresenter>
                              </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
                <!-- Inherit the ContentControl style for Button -->
                <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ContentControl}}"></Style>
                <!-- Inherit the ContentControl style for Label -->
                <Style TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ContentControl}}"></Style>
            </StackPanel.Resources>

            <Button Content="Some_Text"></Button>
            <Button Content="Some__Text"></Button>
            <Button Content="Som_e_Text"></Button>
            <Label Content="Some_Text"></Label>
            <Label Content="Some__Text"></Label>
            <Label Content="Som_e_Text"></Label>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```