# WPF ToolTip and text wrapping for expander

Tags: wpf, tooltip, expander

I have an expander:

```
 <Expander Header="{Binding Name}" IsExpanded="False" >
```

How do i add a ToolTip for it?

And another question, the Name of the header is long and for some reason the expander left one of the characters in **the middle** of the Name.

For example:

- Name is - something_second
- Display shows: somethingsecond

What could it be?

I thought about making it wrap the text but couldn't figure how to do so.

**EDIT:**

Ok so i managed to make a tooltip, i user a static resource. 
But still the text is cutted for some unreasonable reason

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable WPF label accelerator key (text underscore is missing)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40733/disable-wpf-label-accelerator-key-text-underscore-is-missing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is an underscore in a label, WPF interprets it as an access key.  One way to get around this is to use a double-underscore, which escapes the access character:

```
public string Name
{
    get { return _name; }
    set { _name = (value ?? "").Replace("_", "__");
}
private string _name;
```

---

Alternately: it is possible to turn off the access character for individual controls, using [`ContentPresenter.RecognizesAccessKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter.recognizesaccesskey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Unfortunately, to make use of this, you typically have to copy/modify the default control template and set any ContentPresenters' "RecognizesAccessKey" property to false.  For `Expander`, for example, you would have modify this part of the [default template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753296%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
<ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1"
                  Margin="4"
                  ContentSource="Header"
                  RecognizesAccessKey="False" />
```

---

One more alternative (and actually probably the easiest).  Use a `TextBlock` for the header -- that will prevent the access key from being used:

```
<Expander IsExpanded="False">
    <Expander.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </Expander.Header>
</Expander>
```

---

**Related Questions**

- [Underscores not displayed in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5117335/1001985)
- [Disable WPF label accelerator key (text underscore is missing)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40733/1001985)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! finally i chose the easy way and it worked.