# Label.Content Not Working Properly

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, label

I am attempting to assign the following string to a label created in XAML from the C# code-behind file: "Recall_AUX_002"

To do this, I am using the following:

```
lblRecall.Content = currentAddress.Recall;
```

When I run the program, the first underscore magically disappears and the result becomes "RecallAUX_002." If I try to assign the same variable to a random text box in the form, with the following code, it works fine:

```
txtGivenName.Content = currentAddress.Recall;
```

Why is the underscore randomly being removed in labels?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Windows thinks that the first "_" character is an "Access Key". That is, its the key that if you hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> it is the character that is underlined.

You can escape it by writing *two* underscores:

```
<Label Content="Recall__AUX_002"/>
```

or by turning the `RecognizeAccessKey` property to false. This is in the content presenter, so you have to modify the `ControlTemplate`

You can also always just switch to using a `TextBlock`, which ignores access keys.

Answer (score 1):

Underscore are considered as access keys. It has to be disabled if you like to display it in the content.

Refer the below link
[Underscores not displayed in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117335/underscores-not-displayed-in-wpf)