# WPF Binding Properties of a new Button Template

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, button, binding

Ok  i have made a new style for the `Buttons` that i want to use in my app. The general idea is to have 10 square `Button` in which i will have an `Image` and under this a `TextBlock`.
My problem is that i want to set my `Image.Source` and my `TextBlock.Text` different for each `Button`.
What im doing is this :

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">

<Border x:Name="Border" CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="1" Background="Gray" BorderBrush="Orange">
   <Grid>
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
       <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image Margin="0,5,0,0" Grid.Row="0" Width="25"  Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
     <TextBlock FontSize="12"/>
   </Grid>
</Border>
```

What should i do in order to make use of my style like this?

```
<Button Style="{DynamicResource MenuButtons}" Text="????" x:Name="LiveB" Source="????" Click="Live_Click"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734825/custom-button-template-in-wpf

There is all you need:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If *all* you need is an image and some text, you can make it work (mis)using the button's `.Tag` and `.Content`:

```
<Style x:Key="MenuButtons" ...

    ...
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
        <Border x:Name="Border" CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="1" Background="Gray" BorderBrush="Orange">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image Width="25"  Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Tag}" />
                <TextBlock FontSize="12" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Row="1" />
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
    ...
```

..and then:

```
<Button Style="{DynamicResource MenuButtons}" x:Name="LiveB" 
        Content="MyText la la la..." Tag="http://programming.enthuses.me/1.png" 
        Click="Live_Click" />
```

If you need more custom content, you need to look at Konstantin Zhukov's comment and `Attached Properties`.

*(Why you can't just use `"{TemplateBinding Tag}"` instead of `"...{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}..."`? I don't know, but `TemplateBinding` is generally a really fragile shortcut that doesn't always do what it's supposed to do...)*

Comment: Thank you very much. That did the trick. I checked your answer istead of Hasan's only because yours was just what i needed. Hasan's answer also works but i prefer do the Binding throught XAML.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is create a a class which will act as DataContext to button

```
Class ButtonDataContext
{
    public String TextBlockText {get;set;}
    public String ImageSource {get;set;}
}
```

then do

`LiveB.DataContext = new ButtonDataContext(){TextBlockText = "text", ImageSource = "Image Path"};`

in control template XAML

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageSource}" Margin="0,5,0,0" Grid.Row="0" Width="25"  Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TextBlockText}" FontSize="12"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this was pretty helpfull. But what i want to do is set the ImageSource and the TextBlockText from the XAML code and not in C#.Any ideas?